# Trying to add a text file into an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, file, filereader

I am trying to take 500 numbers in this text file and store them into an array, it keeps giving me random numbers that aren't in my text file at all. I've also changed a few things and it is saying that there is conflicting types for my fp_read

```
#include<stdio.h>

int ch;
int X[500];

    FILE*fp_read = NULL;
    fp_read = fopen("random_numbers.txt","r");

int main()
{

    for(i=0;i<499;i++)
    {
        if(ch==EOF)
        {
            printf("End of File\n");
        }
        else
        {
            ch = (fgetc(fp));
            X[i]=ch;
            printf("%d,"X[i]);
        }
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgetc()` is for reading characters one at a time, not integers expressed as digit strings. With ASCII encoding, a `'0'` in the file will show as 48.

Comment: how do I fix that?

Comment: Explore the use of `fscanf()`.

Comment: You don't "fix" it, because it's not broken.

Comment: `while(i < 500 && fscanf(fp_read, "%d", &X[i]) == 1) { i++; }`

Comment: Your code never reads anything from `fp_read`. Also, you need to use `fclose` to close `fp_read` before your program exits.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the quick answer but try to use atoi or strtol to convert the character to integer or add -48 because '0' in ascii is 48

Answer (score 0):

You are interpreting the character codes of the digits used to encode the textual numbers, which is probably not at all what you want. For instance in UTF-8 the number "12" consists of the two code points `1` and `2`, which encode as the two 8-bit values `49` and `50`.

For line-based input, it's almost always best to read whole lines into a suitably large buffer, then parse that. That is more robust than parsing the stream itself.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * const fp = fopen("random-numbers.txt", "rt");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "**File open failed\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    int numbers[500];
    int index = 0;
    char line[1024];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
    {
      if(index >= sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers)
        break;
      numbers[index++] = (int) strtol(line, NULL, 10);
    }

    printf("Read these numbers:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
      printf("%d: %d\n", i, numbers[i]);

    return 0;
}
```